# Не растягиваются input элементы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Почему `input` элемент не растягивается по ширине родительского окна? Внешний отступов справа нету.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Пробовал переопределять стили для `input { width: 100%; }` – не помогло. Переопределял в HTML через атрибут `style` – тоже не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитал документацию bootstrap и нашел там, что все `input` по умолчанию растягиваются на всю ширину родительского контейнера.

Решение оказалось совсем там где не ожидал: при создании проекта ASP.NET MVC в Visual Studio на Basic шаблоне добавляется `Site.css`, там то и было

```
input, select, textarea {
   max-width: 280px;
}
```

Для корректной работы удалил данное правило.